# Mysql IN query with sub condition

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named cities and cfgval
If the siteid condition is true then my queries second part

```
SELECT cfgval FROM sitecfg where cfg='affiliate_sitecityidlock' and siteid=24
```

will return  `"18,20,12,15,22,4,3,9,"`

with a trailing comma, I have removed this by using
`SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM` query.
But when I am putting all queries together it just return only one row, my query is shown below

```
select * from cities  where siteid=0 and id 
IN(
   SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM
     (SELECT cfgval FROM sitecfg where cfg='affiliate_sitecityidlock' 
       and siteid=24)
     )
  )
```

If I am substitute with direct values ie,
`select * from cities  where siteid=0 and id IN(18,20,12,15,22,4,3,9)` it will return all rows , i am stuck with this problem

Comment: Are you sure the query with direct values returns all the rows and you do need `TRIM` because there is no trailing comma will be returned?

Comment: There is a trailing comma come in my result set thats why I added the TRIM function.When I am substituted with direct values it returns all the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `cfgval` returns a single row with a comma delimited column, you can use the [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cities
WHERE siteid=0 
  AND FIND_IN_SET(id, (
   SELECT SUBSTRING(cfgval, 2)
   FROM sitecfg 
   WHERE cfg='affiliate_sitecityidlock' 
       AND siteid=24
    )
  )
```

Note: Since this is using a function, indexes cannot be used, you should think about storing the `cfgval` in multiple rows.

Comment: Hi The Scrum Meister, This query returns all the correct data except my first row

Comment: Hi The Scrum Meister, Thanks once again just change substring(cfgval,1) it returns the correct data .

Comment: @user811755 you can remove the `SUBSTRING()`, i misread your question and thought you had a leading comma.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what your problem is: you think that the sub select will return a comma delimited list of ids and you have to trim the last comma...  No.  Try this:

```
select * from cities
where siteid=0 
and id IN (SELECT cfgval FROM sitecfg where cfg='affiliate_sitecityidlock' and siteid=24)
```

Comment: Hi Bohemian, It just return only a single row of data it correspondes to the first value of IN()

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your query should look like this

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE siteid=0 AND LOCATE(CONCAT(',', id, ','),
CONCAT(',', (SELECT cfgval FROM sitecfg WHERE cfg='affiliate_sitecityidlock' AND siteid=24))
```